# How to add mouse event to QLineEdit

Tags: qt

I am using a QLineEdit to search for specific patterns which contains the text:"ENTER THE SEARCH PATTERN" by default.. So how can I clear the QLineEdit as soon as I click anywhere on the LineEdit??
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement that on your own, as the feature is already there: Use [QLineEdit::setPlaceholderText](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) (Qt 4.7 and above):

```
QLineEdit* le = new QLineEdit;
...
le->setPlaceholderText(tr("Enter the search pattern"));
```

The placeholder text will be displayed if the line edit is otherwise empty and has no focus.

For older Qt versions, one could implement the feature by reimplementing focusInEvent and focusOutEvent (focusIn: clear the placeholder text; focusOut: restore it). I would strongly suggest to upgrade to a recent Qt version though, if the project allows it.

Comment: The program gives an error saying setPlaceholderText is not a member od qLineEdit.

Comment: Your Qt version might be too old, the feature was introduced in Qt 4.7.